# How to create a RPM using native packager from a project with multiple main methods?

Tags: scala, sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I have a sbt project from which i'd like to create a RPM package using the sbt native packager.

For another project with only one main method everything works fine.
But for the project containing multiple main methods the start script (bin/) does not get generated.

Couldn't figure out how to specify the method to use.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify main class in your build:

```
mainClass in Compile := Some("some.class.name")
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works but only for the nominated class. Ideally, one would like to specify more than one main method resulting in more than one executable. Any ideas?